# FPS efficiency for 'attack counter'

Tags: javascript, beginner, performance, collision, battle-simulation

I have a code snippet which I wish to improve to increase my program's FPS, but as a beginner in JavaScript, I do not know how. I know the problem, which is the fact my counter mechanism used to delay attacks is causing lag. I just don't know how to change my code to minimize this lag. I am looking for helpful criticism and code examples to improve my code.

I am going to provide the entire function my code snippet is in so you can relate to it. (I have been told this will help debuggers elsewhere.)

The function to optimize:

```
var updateMobs = function() { // Called in a loop at 30 FPS

    for (var b = 0; b < mobsBlue.length; b++) { // The length of both lists is at max 60
        BM = mobsBlue[b]
        BM.x = BM.x - BM.object.speed

        doCollision(BM, redBase, BM)
        doCollision(BM, debugPlayer, BM)
        if (BM.x < 0){
            mobsBlue.splice(br, 1)
        }
        BM.Draw(ctx, false)

    }
    for (var r = 0; r < mobsRed.length; r++) {
        RM = mobsRed[r]
        RM.x = RM.x + RM.object.speed

        doCollision(RM, blueBase, RM)
        doCollision(RM, debugPlayer, RM)
        if (RM.x > 1350){
            mobsRed.splice(r, 1)
        }
        RM.Draw(ctx, false)


        for (var br = 0; br < mobsBlue.length; br++) {
            BM = mobsBlue[br]

            if (doCollision(RM, BM, collisionNull) == true) { // ATTACKING
                BM.x = BM.x + BM.object.speed
                RM.x = RM.x - RM.object.speed

                if (BM.object.attackTime == 500 || RM.object.attackTime == 500) {
                    if (BM.object.armourType == 'light') {
                        BM.object.health = BM.object.health - RM.object.lightDamage
                    } 
                    if (BM.object.armourType == 'heavy') {
                        BM.object.health = BM.object.health - RM.object.heavyDamage
                    }
                    if (RM.object.armourType == 'light') {
                        RM.object.health = RM.object.health - BM.object.lightDamage
                    }
                    if (RM.object.armourType == 'heavy') {
                        RM.object.health = RM.object.health - BM.object.heavyDamage

                    }
                    if (BM.object.health <= 0) {
                        mobsBlue.splice(br, 1)
                    }
                    if (RM.object.health <= 0) {
                        mobsRed.splice(r, 1)

                    }
                    BM.object.attackTime = 0
                    RM.object.attackTime = 0

                }
                BM.object.attackTime = BM.object.attackTime + 1
                RM.object.attackTime = RM.object.attackTime + 1

            }



            BM.Draw(ctx, false)
            RM.Draw(ctx, false)
        }


    }
}
```

The `doCollision` and `moveOutside` functions:

```
var doCollision = function(rect1, rect2, objectToMove) {
    if (rect1.x + rect1.w > rect2.x &&
        rect1.x < rect2.x + rect2.w &&
        rect1.y + rect1.h > rect2.y &&
        rect1.y < rect2.y + rect2.h) {
        if (objectToMove === rect1) {
            moveOutside(objectToMove, rect2);
            return true
        } else if (objectToMove === rect2) {
            moveOutside(objectToMove, rect1);
            return true
        }
        return true
    };
};

var moveOutside = function(rectToMove, otherRect) {
    // Determine if the overlap is due more to x or to y,
    // then perform the appropriate move

    var moveOverOtherX = rectToMove.x + rectToMove.w - otherRect.x;
    var otherOverMoveX = otherRect.x + otherRect.w - rectToMove.x;

    var moveOverOtherY = rectToMove.y + rectToMove.h - otherRect.y;
    var otherOverMoveY = otherRect.y + otherRect.h - rectToMove.y;

    var minOver = Math.min(moveOverOtherX, otherOverMoveX, moveOverOtherY, otherOverMoveY);

    if (minOver == moveOverOtherX) {
        rectToMove.x = otherRect.x - rectToMove.w;
    } else if (minOver == otherOverMoveX) {
        rectToMove.x = otherRect.x + otherRect.w;
    } else if (minOver == moveOverOtherY) {
        rectToMove.y = otherRect.y - rectToMove.h;
    } else {
        rectToMove.y = otherRect.y + otherRect.h;
    };
};
```

I am looking for more answers.

Comment: Could you show us `doCollision()` as well?

Comment: added `doCollision` and the related `moveOutside`

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good way, but I think object comparison is very heavy. I suggest that you change the type of parameter, i.e. `objectToMove` (true means `rect1`, and false means `rect2`). Logical operations are light.

I also suggest that you change the `if` with `minOver` and others to switch-case (some other where comparing the same subject too).

Comment: The first idea i cannot do, and the second idea dosent make sense to me... I am looking for more awnsers

Comment: I suggest you the second because Switch-Case is comparing value (i.e. minOver) at only once, but If is comparing  at the number of If were written.